# SQL to convert column data to rows and increment column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've been using SQL for a while, but I'm still a noob so I am coming here for help.
I searched around the site already but didn't quite find what I'm looking to accomplish.

I want to use SQL to take Two Columns that look like this:

```
VisitNumber ID
39332       759666
39332       769445
39332       775795
40329       762595
40329       769447
40329       775796
40329       783782
39332       783781
39332       861130
```

To This:

```
VistNumber  ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
39332       759666  769445  775795  783781  861130
40329       762595  769447  775796  783782  NULL
```

I was thinking of using PIVOT but I'm not sure exactly how to do the pivot portion since I'm not using Count(), Min(), Max(), etc..
Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use MSSQL server ?

Comment: Yes I am using MSSQL Server.

Comment: do you need the ID's in seperate columns, or a list? can there be more than 5 ID's for a VisitNumber ?

Comment: I do need the IDs in separate columns and there would only be a maximum of 5 IDs for a VisitNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server there are several different ways that you can get the result but all of them involve using `row_number()`.

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select visitnumber,
  max(case when seq=1 then id end) ID1,
  max(case when seq=2 then id end) ID2,
  max(case when seq=3 then id end) ID3,
  max(case when seq=4 then id end) ID4,
  max(case when seq=5 then id end) ID5
from
(
  select visitnumber, id,
    row_number() over(partition by visitnumber 
                      order by id) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by visitnumber;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd4b0/3)

You can use the PIVOT function:

```
select visitnumber, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5
from
(
  select visitnumber, id,
    'ID'+cast(row_number() over(partition by visitnumber 
                                order by id) as varchar(10)) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(id)
  for seq in (ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd4b0/1). You stated that you would only have a maximum of 5 id's but if you had an unknown number, then you could use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('ID'+cast(row_number() over(partition by visitnumber 
                                order by id) as varchar(10))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT visitnumber,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select visitnumber, id,
                  ''ID''+cast(row_number() over(partition by visitnumber 
                                              order by id) as varchar(10)) seq
               from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(id)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd4b0/2). All versions will give a result:

```
| VISITNUMBER |    ID1 |    ID2 |    ID3 |    ID4 |    ID5 |
------------------------------------------------------------
|       39332 | 759666 | 769445 | 775795 | 783781 | 861130 |
|       40329 | 762595 | 769447 | 775796 | 783782 | (null) |
```

Comment: like the pivot solution

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as
(

select t.VisitNumber,
       t.Id,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY VisitNumber 
                          ORDER BY ID) rn
from t
)

SELECT VisitNumber, 
[1], [2], [3], [4],[5]
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(
AVG(ID)
FOR RN IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5])
) AS PivotTable
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a307e/6)

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I selected the other as the answer though since if anyone else that runs into my problem would have more than 5 IDs they can use that one.